# Looking for specific text and save it into variable

Tags: perl, fasta

I am looking for the easiest way to look for text in huge file and save it into same variables for later use.

The file format is:

```
>gi|24585363|ref|NP_724239.1| short neuropeptide F precursor [Drosophila melanogaster]
MFHLKRELSQGCALALICLVSLQMQQPAQAEVSSAQGTPLSNLYDNLLQREYAGPVVFPNHQVERKAQRS
PSLRLRFGRSDPDMLNSIVEKRWFGDVNQKPIRSPSLRLRFGRRDPSLPQMRRTAYDDLLERELTLNSQQ
QQQQLGTEPDSDLGADYDGLYERVVRKPQRLRWGRSVPQFEANNADNEQIERSQWYNSLLNSDKMRRMLV
ALQQQYEIPENVASYANDEDTDTDLNNDTSEFQREVRKPMRLRWGRSTGKAPSEQKHTPEETSSIPPKTQ
N
>gi|442619471|ref|NP_001262643.1| neuropeptide F, isoform C [Drosophila melanogaster]
MCQTMRCILVACVALALLAAGCRVEASNSRPPRKNDVNTMADAYKFLQDLDTYYGDRARVRFGKRGSLMD
ILRNHEMDNINLGKNANNGGEFARGFNEEEIF
>gi|442619469|ref|NP_001262642.1| neuropeptide F, isoform B [Drosophila melanogaster]
MCQTMRCILVACVALALLAAGCRVEASNSRPPRKNDVNTMADAYKFLQDLDTYYGDRARVRFGKRGSLMD
ILRNHEMDNINLGKNANNGGEFARGFNEEEIF
```

every sequence starts with ">"

I tried this:

```
open (FILE, $fastaFile);
while (<FILE>) {
chomp;
($name, $name2) = split(/:/);

print "Name: $name\n";
print "Name2: $name2\n";

} close (FILE);

exit;
```

I never needed to look for specific text. Perhaps it would be easy to use grep only I don´t know that.

The bigest problem for me is that I have in another file result from my other program and I need to find these results in another file.

My main program gave me these results:

```
>gi|24585363|ref|NP_724239.1|
>gi|442619469|ref|NP_001262642.1|
```

and I need to find it in the second file and save this into $name and into $sequence put the sequnces for that name.:

```
$name = ">gi|24585363|ref|NP_724239.1|"
$sequnce = "MFHLKRELSQGCALALICLVSLQMQQPAQAEVSSAQGTPLSNLYDNLLQREYAGPVVFPNHQVERKAQRS
    PSLRLRFGRSDPDMLNSIVEKRWFGDVNQKPIRSPSLRLRFGRRDPSLPQMRRTAYDDLLERELTLNSQQ
    QQQQLGTEPDSDLGADYDGLYERVVRKPQRLRWGRSVPQFEANNADNEQIERSQWYNSLLNSDKMRRMLV
    ALQQQYEIPENVASYANDEDTDTDLNNDTSEFQREVRKPMRLRWGRSTGKAPSEQKHTPEETSSIPPKTQ
    N"
```

Can anyone give me advice on how to proceed? If use grep or some another way to get there.

Comment: Your input doesn't contain a single colon, why do you `split` on `/:/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help get you what you want. You will need to install Bio Perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Bio::SeqIO;

my $seqFile = Bio::SeqIO->new('-format' => 'fasta', '-file' => 'myFasta.fasta');
while((my $seqObj = $seqFile->next_seq())){
     print "Seen Sequence " . $seqObj->display_id . "\n";
     print "Sequence: " . $seqObj->seq() . "\n";
}
```